# Why global arrays does not consume memory in readonly mode?

Tags: c++, memory, global-variables

The following code declare a global array (256 MiB) and calculate sum of it's items.

This program consumes **188 KiB** when runing:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int buffer_len = 256 * 1024 * 1024; // 256 MB
unsigned char buffer[buffer_len];

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < buffer_len; i++)
            sum += buffer[i];

        cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The following code is like the above code, but sets array elements to random value before calculating the sum of array items.

This program consumes **256.1 MiB** when runing:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int buffer_len = 256 * 1024 * 1024; // 256 MB
unsigned char buffer[buffer_len];

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // ********** Changing array items.
        for(int i = 0; i < buffer_len; i++)
            buffer[i] = std::rand() % 256;
        // **********

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < buffer_len; i++)
            sum += buffer[i];

        cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Why global arrays does not consume memory in readonly mode (188K vs 256M)?

- My Compiler: GCC
- MY OS: Ubuntu 20.04

---

**Update**:

In my real scenario I will generate the buffer with `xxd` command, so it's elements are not zero:

`$ xxd -i buffer.dat buffer.cpp`

Comment: what makes you conclude that it is the array that causes the difference? What compiler flags did you use ?

Comment: How do you know how much memory a program uses? How are you measuring it?

Comment: Isn't the first version undefined behavior because you're reading from values that haven't been initialized? Seems like that gives the compiler considerably more leeway to not bother writing things down.

Comment: @NathanPierson No, `buffer` is `static` so it is initialized with `0`.

Comment: @NathanPierson nah, globals are 0-initialized.

Comment: Can you share the gcc flags you're using to compile? It's very possible in your first example `buffer` is being optimized away entirely.

Comment: If the compiler determines that you're using undefined behavior, it's free to modify your program in ways that don't make sense.

Comment: @TimRandall I measure memory usage with `System Monitor`

Comment: Most likely, in the first example compiler can see that all you are doing here is adding zeros a lot of time, and array is not really needed, so everything is optimized out. In the second case, compiler does need storage to store your random values.

Comment: In the first example, you can demonstrate that `buffer[i]` is `0`, so `sum` is always `0`, so your program can just be `while(true) { cout << "Sum: " << 0 << endl;`. Your array can be optimized out as it is never used.

Comment: @MarkRansom there is no undefined behavior.

Comment: @JonReeves `$ g++ main.cpp -o mytest`

Comment: @NathanPierson Global variables get automagically zero initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's much speculation in the comments that this behavior is explained by compiler optimizations, but OP's use of g++ (i.e. without optimization) doesn't support this, and neither does the assembly output on the same architecture, which clearly shows `buffer` being used:

```
buffer:
        .zero   268435456
        .section        .rodata
```

...

```
.L3:
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cmpl    $268435455, %eax
        ja      .L2
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        leaq    buffer(%rip), %rdx
        movzbl  (%rax,%rdx), %eax
        movzbl  %al, %eax
        addl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
        jmp     .L3
```

The real reason you're seeing this behavior is the use of [Copy On Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) in the kernel's VM system. Essentially for a large buffer of zeros like you have here, the kernel will create a single "zero page" and point all pages in `buffer` to this page. Only when the page is written will it get allocated.

This is actually true in your second example as well (i.e. the behavior is the same), but you're touching every page with data, which forces the memory to be "paged in" for the entire buffer. Try only writing `buffer_len/2`, and you'll see that 128.2MiB of memory gets allocated by the process. Half of the true size of the buffer:

[image: half initialized]

Here's also a helpful summary from Wikipedia:

> The copy-on-write technique can be extended to support efficient memory allocation by having a page of physical memory filled with zeros. When the memory is allocated, all the pages returned refer to the page of zeros and are all marked copy-on-write. This way, physical memory is not allocated for the process until data is written, allowing processes to reserve more virtual memory than physical memory and use memory sparsely, at the risk of running out of virtual address space.